# adding datetime in mysql with codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, codeigniter

how do i add datetime ( not current timestamp) but any date and time in 'datetime' field of mysql database in the format 2011-03-18 18:37:06 from php ? does jquery calendar allow time as well or what is the easy way to do so ? any help would be greatly appreceated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

86400 seconds in a day, times number of days.. and add it to current time.

```
$nextWeek = time()+86400*7;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $nextWeek);
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>`

not sure how this is CI related.

Comment: "( not current timestamp) but any date and time..."

Comment: yes not current timestamp for example i want to add date and time for  1 week later or after 25 days later